# Can I use a maptool macro within a table?

Tags: maptool

I am trying to get my random encounter table to automatically roll the number of creatures... Basically [r: 1d4] "creature", but no joy with that method...

Comment: What end result are you after? Do you want it to just output the number of creatures ("1 creature", "2 creatures", etc), or do you want it to output the actual creatures from that random encounter table?

Comment: I just want it to output a chat text telling me "x number of creatures"... Not ready to try having a macro place a token yet.